# ¿Como acceder a proyecto en red a travez de un nombre(dominio o no) y no por ip en red Lan / wan?

Tags: php, python, phpmyadmin, xampp, seguridad

Tengo proyecto en mi pc (php/python) puerto 8080 (192.168.100:8080/miproy) donde puedo acceder desde otra pc en red a traves de la ip de esre pequeño servidor.
Pero cono es obvio la lo y para proteger deseo acceder tanto en mi red como fuera a travez de un nombre.
He probado adicionando. 127.0.0.1 en la pc. Pero sólo funciona localmente.
Así mismo deseo adquirir un dominio y redirigir.
Cuál seria el correcto procedimiento en ambos casos.(sólo mi Lan y mas adelante con dominio).
Gracias

Comment: Hay varias maneras de conseguirlo, pero depende de la infraestructura de red que dispongas (sistema operativo, software y hardware de conectividad, servidores, etc.) y el alcance. Comienza intentando con el [archivo de hosts](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo_hosts).

Comment: Tengo el proyecto en windows 10. Instalado el Xampp. Y ya modifique el arhivos hosts como 127.0.0.1 nombreproyecto. Funciona sólo en la pc que se modificó pero no desde otros ordenadores.La red es básica. Switch router general. Alguna orientación?? O paper. Estoy en busqueda pero no encuentro algo claro. Lo mismo para hacerlo si adquiero un hosting

Comment: No sirve ... necesitas un router o swicth programable en el cual pueda decir que la url local: http://peppito.intranet apunta a tu ip: 192.168.100 en el puerto 8080

Comment: todo lo que haces en tu archivo host solo ayuda o resuelve en el problema en tu equipo... tendrias que ir de maquina en maquina editando tus archivos host indicando / agregando la regla

Comment: si adquieres un hosting no necesitas hacer nada ... el hosting web esta en internet y viene preconfigurado con el dominio que hayas comprado tambien ...

Comment: Este tema no tiene que ver en nada con programacion, el como levantar en tu red el  reconocimiento de tu equipo y de tu domino es tema de networking y super usuarios, no es un problema de programacion